# Xcode not showing list of Simulators

Tags: xcode, simulator

I had a problem of other side(not simulator), and I tried to solve the problem to do this and that.

And than my Xcode doesn't not show list of Simulators.

I try to do everything to show list but I can't.(delete and reinstall Xcode, delete and reinstall ios 14.3 simulator ...)

Here are images for current my Xcode state and Xcode version is 12.5.1.

I can't work anything because of this.

Please help.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

It may be due to your project minimum version being greater than 14.3. Go to **TARGETS -> General -> Deployment Info** then check the minimum iOS version, if it is greater than 14.3 change to a lower version or 14.3 itself.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In this window, click the Plus button at the lower left and make a new simulator. Do that as many times as you wish.

[image]